# Handle timeouts in WCF service

Tags: wcf, service, error-handling, timeout

I would like to know what is a proper way to handle timeouts in a WCF service.

I have a service that uses sessions. The client does a Connect, various calls (as the user interacts with the client app) and then, at some point, does a Disconnect. The Disconnect operation performs a clean-up on the server (such as releasing COM objects). However, the client can (abnormally) terminate (for various reasons) without calling Disconnect. After the `receiveTimeout` expires, the services is aborted. I need to handle this in a way that allows me to proper clean-up the session. How can I do that?

Is there an event I can handle? An interface that I can implement and customize the service with it? I have looked, but did not find something. `IErrorHandler` does not help with the timeouts.

I have thought of a timer on the service that is reset every time a call is made to the service. When the timer elapses, the client is considered disconnected and the service can clean-up the session. Is this appropriate? (This interval should be always smaller than the `receiveTimeout` of the binding.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff183865.aspx, WCF sessions timeout by default after 10 minutes or whatever the receiveTimeout specifies. If your service class implements IDisposable, I believe the Dispose() call should come in at this time, which would give you a second/last chance to clean up any outstanding resources.